# Creating a square with mousedown

Tags: javascript, mousedown

I want a red square to appear where I click on the canvas with my mouse, but I'm having trouble getting the square to appear on the canvas when I click on it. The function start contains window.addEventListener() which is supposed to be creating a component on the mouseclick, but I'm not sure if I am missing something or if I'm just completely wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta = name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="start() {
    gameArea.start();
}

var gameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 840;
        this.canvas.height = 540;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);

//I don't know what Im doing wrong here
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
        })
    }
}

//and here
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have invalid `body` tag, missing opening `script` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
   const {layerX, layerY} = e;
   const rectSize = 30;
   this.context.fillStyle = 'red';
   this.context.fillRect(layerX - rectSize / 2, layerY - rectSize / 2, rectSize, rectSize);
});
```

you passed a function () {} which had no context of your `gameArea`. The other part is a canvas api.